# How to write @SpringBootTest for app with @ComponentScan and JPA repositories

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

I find it extremely hard to write @SpringBootTest if you use @ComponentScan and Jpa repositories. Can someone advice? This should be super-trivial stuff, but it's not documented anywhere.

```
@SpringBootApplication  
@ComponentScan(
        excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class),
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.class) },
        basePackageClasses = {Main.class, Other.class})
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

and one of discovered Configuration classes has:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("jpa")
```

Now I want to create test, which will enable ideally just a subset of JPA repositories AND exactly nothing else, unless I tell so. Namely, no configuration from production source code. This seems to be close to impossible to express. This is where I was able to get:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Import(TestIT.TestConfig.class)
public class TestIT {

    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories("jpa")
    @AutoConfigureDataJpa
    @AutoConfigurationPackage
    public static class TestConfig {
        //here will be beans for test.
    }
```

so this configuration produces error

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type ...my jpa repository class`

which probably means, that `jpa` package isn't among autoconfigured packages. No idea how to add it if it's even possible.

OK, another approach. Some sources recommends this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Import(TestIT.TestConfig.class)
public class TestIT {

    EnableJpaRepositories("jpa")
    @EntityScan(basePackages = "jpa.entities")
    //@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public static class TestConfig {
        //here will be beans for test.
    }
```

but this one fails with `caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!`

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after a lot of searching (in vain) and even more trying, I think I have answer.

To recap:

you have main class (thanks @Bhushan Shinde):

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {Main.class, Other.class})
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

and some configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("jpa")
public class Config
```

So to use SpringBootTest and configure everything from scratch for test, ignoring production configurations, you go:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE,
        classes = TestIT.TestConfig.class)
//@Import(TestIT.TestConfig.class)
public class TestIT {

    @Configuration
    @AutoConfigureDataJpa
    @EnableJpaRepositories("jpa") //fake package names, obviously
    @EntityScan(basePackages = "jpa.entities")
//    @TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public static class TestConfig {
         //test related beans & config.
    }

    //tests here.
}
```

maybe there is something extra here, but after day of googling & trying this is good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no specific need to add @ComponentScan in your main application startup file. `@SpringBootApplication` is sufficient.

Now regarding the test cases:
I use powermockito all my test cases usually look like this:-

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ ContextProvider.class, ConfigurationUtils.class, Utils.class })
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class TestIT {
```

IN the clause `@PrepareForTest` mention all the classes which u would mention with the annotation @Mock.
 for e.g.
No need to mention any of the repo(DAO layer interfaces where we write our queries) interfaces. So ur repo declaration would be like:

```
private SoftwareRepo softwareRepo;
```

And u would use it in while execution is

```
softwareInventoryRepo = PowerMockito.mock(SoftwareRepo.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for hints, not sure if it's related though: I don't want unit testing (via any mocking) I want integration testing with real classes. Regarding `@ComponentScan`: you're probably right, I put it in there just to be able to specify basePackagesClasses, but now I see this is also available in `@SpringBootApplication`, so thank s about that.